# Maximal common isotropic subspace for a finite family of skewforms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, galois-theory, matrix-theory, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be  a vector space of dimension $n$  over a field $F$. An alternating bilinear form  $\alpha\colon V \times V \rightarrow F $ will be called a skewform. A subspace $W$ is isotropic for $\alpha$ if $\alpha(x,y) = 0$ for all $x,y \in W$.
More generally, if $\alpha = \{\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2},\dotsc,\alpha_{k}\}$ is a collection of $k$ skew forms on $V$  then a subspace $ W $ is isotropic for $ \alpha $ if it is isotropic for each $ \alpha_{i} $.
Given a collection  $ \alpha $ of $k$ skewforms, let $ m(\alpha) $ be the dimension of the largest isotropic subspace for $\alpha$. Then we define  $d(F,n,k) = \min_{\alpha} m(\alpha) $.

We set  $ s_{n}(F) $ to be that positive integer $r$ satisfying  $d(F,n,r)= 1$ and $d(F,n,r-1)  \geq 2$.
Now I am interested when $ F $ is $\mathbb{Q}$. We know that $s_{2n}(\mathbb{Q}) = 2n$ or $2n-1$ . My question is:

1. For which values of $2n$, $ s_{2n}(\mathbb{Q} )= 2n-1 $? That is for which values of $2n$ there exists $2n-1$ skewforms which have no common isotropic subspaces of dimension $> 1$. Already I know that for $2n=4$ or $ 8 $, $ s_{2n}(\mathbb{Q} )= 2n-1$.
2. What is the value of $s_{6}(\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Why do you know that $s_{2n}(\mathbb Q)$ is either $2n$ or $2n-1$?

Comment: What is the relevance of [tag:noncommutative-algebra] to the problem?

Comment: Dear @WillSawin for this you have to do some construction,but I believed that only the result is important . you can consider the question as : " can you find 5 skew foms in 6 dimensional space which have no common isotropic subspace is of dim 2 ??"

Comment: Echoing @WillSawin's comment, I, too, would be interested to see what kind of method gives you the result for $s_{2n}(\mathbb Q)$. In particular, for example, does it really use the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is what it is (quotient field of $\mathbb Z$, a fairly special ring), or does it work for infinite fields of characteristic not $2$? Your question is an interesting dual/variant of things I've thought about... Please clarify/expand? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose M be a subspace of Alt(V) and u an element of $ V^{*} then we set $ M_{u} = {f \in M : u \in  $ rad f $ \} and $ V_{u}^{M} = { v \in V : f(u,v) = 0 for all f \in M }. $ Then you can easily prove that $ dim M -  dim M_{u} = dim v - dim V_{u}^{M} $ . So we have $ dim M_{u} = s_{n}(F)  - (n-1) $ for all $ u \in V^{*} $ . Thus $ s_{n}(F) \geq n-1 $. also $\ mathbb{Q} $ has cyclic extension of degree n so we can show $ d(F,n,n)= 1 $ hence $ s_{2n}(\mathbb{Q}) = 2n $ or $2n-1 $. But if you consider only finite fields (char $ \neq 2 $ ) then  $ s_{2n}(\mathbb{Q}) = 2n $ .

Comment: @SugataMandal's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398253/maximal-common-isotropic-subspace-for-a-finite-family-of-skewforms#comment1020406_398253), with fixed TeX, I think:  "Let $M$ be a subspace of $\operatorname{Alt}(V)$ and $u$ an element of $V^*$.  Then we set $M_u = \{f \in M : u \in \operatorname{rad}(f)\}$ and $V_u^M = \{v \in V : \text{$f(u, v) = 0$ for all $f \in M$}\}$.  Then you can easily prove that $\dim M - \dim M_u = \dim V - \dim V_u^M$.  So we have $\dim M_u = s_n(F) - (n - 1)$ for all $u \in V^*$.  […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1020456)"

Comment: "[…](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398253/maximal-common-isotropic-subspace-for-a-finite-family-of-skewforms#comment1020455_398253) Thus $s_n(F) \ge n - 1$.  Also $\mathbb Q$ has cyclic extensions of degree $n$, so we can show $d(F, n, n) = 1$, hence $s_{2n}(\mathbb Q)$ equals $2n$ or $2n - 1$.  But if you consider only finite fields ($\operatorname{char} \ne 2$) then $s_{2n}(\mathbb Q) = 2n$."  @SugataMandal, should that be $s_{2n}(F) = 2n$, $F$ the finite field, at the end?

Comment: @LSpice I think the $*$s were not supposed to be there in the original.

Comment: My attempt to write this argument with more details: To show $s_{2n}(\mathbb Q) = 2n-1$ or $2n-2$, we must show that every collection of $2n-2$ skewforms has a $2$-dimensional isotropic subspace and exhibit a collection of $2n$ skewforms without a $2$-dimensional isotropic subspace. For the first step, choose a vector $u\in V$ and consider the subspace of $v\in V$ such that $\alpha_i(u,v)=0$ for all skewforms $\alpha_i$.

Comment: The number of skewforms is $2n-2$, so this subspace has dimension at least $2$, so we can choose $v$ in this subspace independent of $u$, and then the subspace generated by $u$ and $v$ is isotropic since $\alpha_i(u,u)=\alpha_i(u,v) = \alpha_i(v,v)=0$.

Comment: For the second step, let $V=F$ be a cyclic extension of $\mathbb Q$ of degree $2n$, with an automorphism $\sigma$ generating its Galois group, and set $\alpha_i (u,v)= L_i ( u \sigma(v) -v \sigma(u))$ for a basis $L_i$ of linear forms $F \to \mathbb Q$. Then $u,v$ will only lie in an isotropic subspace if $u \sigma(v) - v \sigma(u) =0$, or equivalently $u/v = \sigma(u/v)$, so $u/v\in \mathbb Q$ and thus $u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent. The first step works over any field, and the second step works over any field with cyclic extensions of degree $2n$.

Comment: If $n=4$ or $8$, let $V$ be the quaternions or octonions over $\mathbb Q$, and set $\alpha_i( u, v) = L_i ( u v^* )$ where $*$ is the conjugation and $L_i$ is a basis of linear forms on the quaternions / octonions mod the identity. (This is skew-symmetric since $(uv^*) = (vu^*)^*$).  If $u,v$ lie in an isotropic subspace then $uv^* \in \mathbb Q$ which sine $v^* v \in \mathbb Q$ implies $u,v$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearly dependent. I think this explains the relationship to noncommutative algebra...

Comment: Yes @LSpice absolutely I wrote their this argumen.

Comment: @WillSawin pure octonions or quaternions are hold for Real field also . But can we construct that type of example or other examples for $ \mathbb{Q} $ when $ 2n = 6 $  I have tried some construction but they all have common isotropic subspace of dim 2.

Comment: I have only the following thought: Given $2n-1$ skew-symmetric forms, the existence of a $v$ linearly independent from $u$ with $\alpha_i(u,v)=0$ for all $i$ is equivalent to the vanishing of a $2n-1 \times 2n-1$ determinant. Viewed as a polynomial in the coordinates of $u$, this determinant is homogeneous of degree $2n-2$, since it can be obtained as one of the minors of the obvious $2n-1 \times 2n$ matrix divided by the corersponding entry of $u$.

Comment: So we're looking for a degree $2n-2$ hypersurface in $\mathbb P^{n-1}$ with no rational solutions, of which there are plenty, mostly (or entirely?) due to real obstructions. For your two examples, this degree $2n-2$ polynomial is the norm of the quaternions or the cube of the norm of the octonions. So one could maybe look for more examples where this polynomial is the $n-1$st power of the sum of squares. The allowable hypersurfaces are the image of a $(2n-1)^2 (n-1)$-dimensional Grassmanian inside a $\binom{4n-3 }{2n-2} -1$ dimensional  space of hypersurfaces, so clearly not all.

Answer (score 2):

$s_{2n}(\mathbb R) \geq  2n$ for $n \neq 1,2,4$.

In particular, one can't show that $s_{2n}(\mathbb Q) = 2n-1$ for these $n$ using real methods.

Proof: Suppose for contradiction that there were $\alpha_1,\dotsc, \alpha_{2n-1}$ skew-symmetric forms on $\mathbb R^{2n}$ such that for any $u$, $v$ linearly independent, we have $\alpha_i (u, v)\neq 0$ for some $i$.

Then we would obtain a parallization of $S^{2n-1}$, as follows: For $u \in S^{2n-1} \subset \mathbb R^{2n}$ (embedded as the unit sphere, say), we can map the tangent space of $S^{2n-1}$ at $u$ to $\mathbb R^{2n-1}$ by mapping a vector $v$ orthogonal to $u$ to $\alpha_1(u,v),\dots, \alpha_{2n-1}(u,v)$. This is injective by assumption, hence an isomorphism, and it varies continuously with $u$, thus gives an isomorphism of the vector bundle with the trivial bundle.

By a classical theorem of algebraic topology, $n=1$, $2$, or $4$. QED.

I explained in the comments ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398253/maximal-common-isotropic-subspace-for-a-finite-family-of-skewforms#comment1020536_398253) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398253/maximal-common-isotropic-subspace-for-a-finite-family-of-skewforms#comment1020538_398253)) how to check that the $u$ such that there exists $v$ linearly independent from $u$ with $\alpha_i (u,v)=0$ for all $i$ form a hypersurface of degree $2n-2$ in $\mathbb P^{2n-1}$. If this hypersurface is smooth, then it is Fano and the Brauer–Manin obstruction vanishes (as long as $n>2$). The above argument shows it has a real point. If it has a $p$-adic point for each prime $p$ (which perhaps can be checked separately), then a conjecture of Colliot-Thélène suggests it should have a rational point.

However, this conjecture is very hard to prove in most special cases. Thus I suspect $s_{2n}(\mathbb Q) = 2n$ to be very hard to prove for these $n$ even if it is true, unless the hypersurface in question has some special geometric structure I am missing that simplifies the problem.

EDIT: Here is what is probably a better way to obtain a hypersurface.

Given skew-symmetric forms $\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_{2n-1}$ on a $2n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$, a vector $u$ lies in an isotropic subspace of rank $\geq 2$ if and only if the map $F^{2n-1} \to V^\vee$ that sends the unit vector $e_i$ to the linear form $v \mapsto \alpha_i (u, v)$ has image of codimension at least $2$ (since its image is contained in the perpendicular to the isotropic), in other words if and only if it has kernel of dimension at least $1$.

Thus, there is a two-dimensional maximal isotropic if and only if some nontrivial linear combination of the $\alpha_i$s is degenerate.

A skew-symmetric form is degenerate if and only if the Pfaffian vanishes. The Pfaffian of a linear combination of the $\alpha_i$s is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $2n-1$ variables, and thus defines a hypersurface of degree $n$ in $\mathbb P^{2n-2}$. We have $s_{2n}(F) = 2n-1$ if and only if, for some collection of $\alpha_i$s, this hypersurface does not have an $F$-rational point.

One advantage of this perspective is that it seems geometrically simpler, being a lower-degree hypersurface in a lower-degree projective space.

Another is that we can describe the singular locus more clearly. Inside the space of all skew-symmetric matrices, the singular locus of the Pfaffian hypersurface is the locus of matrices of rank $\leq 2n-4$, which has codimension $6$.

Thus for a generic $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{2n-1}$, the singular locus of this hypersurface in $\mathbb P^{2n-1}$ has codimension $6$. In particular, for $n=3$, generically we get a smooth cubic threefold. I don't know any approach to the existence of rational points on such varieties.

Comment: So, apparently, the precise answer _does_ depend on some arithmetic!?! Very interesting.

Comment: @paulgarrett In fact I think one can check $s(2n,\mathbb C)= 4n-3$ since every linear slice of the Grassmanian can only reduce the dimension by $1$, so there is a really big difference between the geometric and arithmetic answer.

Comment: Dear @Will Sawin  if we take $\Mathbb{R} $ instead  of $\Mathbb{Q} $ then there exists  always  a two dimensional common isotropic subspace, Can you find any example for $\Mathbb{Q} $ such that there  is no isotropic  subspace  of dim 2 or $ s_{6}(\Mathbb{Q}) $ can't equal to 5. If $s_{6}(\Mathbb{Q}) =5  $  then there is 5 dimensional  subspace  of alternating  forms and every every element has non zero .pfaffian.