# Trivial rational solution of a system of hyperplanes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, projective-geometry, grassmannians, multilinear-algebra

Let us consider a vector space $ V $ over $ \mathbb{Q} $ of dim $6$. We denote all the two dimensional subspace in $ V $ by $ G(2,6) $ (The Grassmanian variety). One can define a map $ p $ from $ G(2,6) $ to $P(\Lambda^{d} V) $ by $ p (U) = u_{1} \wedge u_{2} $, where  $ U \in G(2,6) $ and $ u_{1},u_{2} $ be a basis of $ U $.
Now we have $ 15 $ Plücker coordinates. We also know that $ G(2,6) $ is the zero set of a system of quadratic Plücker
polynomials. Now we define $ 5 $ hyperplanes as a linear combination of Plücker coordinates :
$ \alpha_{i} = \sum_{j,k} a_{jk}^{i} p_{jk} $ for all $ 1 \leq i \leq 5  $  , where  $ p_{jk} $ are the Plücker coordinates. Also $ a_{jk} \in \mathbb{Q} $.

```
Now my question is 
 Can there exists 5  hyperplane in this above form such that their intersection with Grassmanian variety has no rational point?
```

Comment: "zero" is not a point of $G(2,6)$.

Comment: Yes @abx you are right all the plucker co ordinate  does  not equal to zero . because zero not lies in  projective space. okay I should edit my question. The question should be has no rational points in their intersections.

Comment: This question is a special case of your previous question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398253/maximal-common-isotropic-subspace-for-a-finite-family-of-skewforms and my comments there might be helpful - specifically, showing that there can be no real obstruction to rational points, and giving two interpretations as a problem of finding rational points on a hypersurface.

Comment: I know how to make examples when you replace the Grassmannian by a “twist” that has a rational point (so not “immediately” explained by a Brauer obstruction).

Comment: @JasonStarr If I understand correctly, you can do this with a single hyperplane (the twist of the Grassmanian looks like triples quaternions modulo left multiplication by quaternions, linear sections correspond to $3 \times 3$ quaternionic Hermitian forms, and any positive definite such form does the trick).

Comment: I guess the cubic hypersurface $3$-fold I constructed is equivalent to the usual construction of a Fano of type $V_3$ from a Fano of type $V_{14}$, see e.g. The Abel–Jacobi Map for a Cubic Threefold
and Periods of Fano Threefolds of Degree 14
A. Iliev and D. Markushevich https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-05/03.pdf which also mentions the classical result that a generic cubic 3-fold arises this way. So it would suffice to find a sufficiently generic cubic 3-fold without a rational point.

Comment: @WillSawin.  You are correct that there are simpler examples over global fields.  The examples that I know have vanishing "elementary obstruction" but fail to have local points.  More generally, there are examples for complete intersections of type $(d_1,\dots,d_c)$ in a twist of the Grassmannian $G(k,n)$ whenever $d_1^2 + \dots + d_c^2 \geq n/k$.  By Ax-Kochen-Ersov, if $d_1^2 + \dots + d_c^2$ is $<n/k$, for all local fields with sufficiently large residue field, there should always be a local point, so these examples are "sharp" in that sense.

Comment: @WillSawin.  You can certainly find a rational cubic threefold without a rational point; you can even find such over a local field.  In fact, a sufficiently general "perturbation" of the zero scheme of the reduced norm of a division algebra of period = index = $3$ over a local field gives such a cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^8$.  Now take a $4$-plane section, and choose a rational cubic threefold that agrees with the local example to high order.

Comment: @WillSawin: to fulfill the cubic 3-fold approach you will have to show that a birational transformation between $V_3$ and $V_{14}$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$; as such transformation is **not** canonical, this might be problematic. Another option would be to find a **Pfaffian** cubic 3-fold with no rational points, because in this case there is a **canonical** Sarkisov link relating it to $V_{14}$.

Comment: @Sasha I was thinking exactly of the result that a generic cubic $3$-fold is Pfaffian. But of course there is a subtlety here that there may not be a $\mathbb Q$-point on the $5$-dimensional moduli space of ways to make it Pfaffian.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is positive. Indeed, the space of all codimension 5 linear sections of $G(2,6)$ is parameterized by $G(5,15)$. For each rational point $P \in G(2,6)$ the set of linear sections containing $P$ is a copy of $G(5,14) \subset G(5,15)$. Therefore, the set of all codimension 5 linear sections of $G(2,6)$ containing a rational point is a countable union of proper subvarieties. Taking any point in its complement, one obtains a linear section with no rational points.

EDIT. As @abx explains in the comments this does not answer the OP's question since it is absolutely non clear if the complement contains at least one point defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I am confused about your argument. It should apply to the intersection of  4 hyperplanes with the Grassmannian $G(2,5)\subset\mathbb{P}^{9}$. But a general such  intersection is a del Pezzo surface of degree 5, which has always a rational point. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I guess the problem is that the OP wants his linear section of $G(2,6)$ to be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Your complement in $G(5,15)$ is a countable intersection of (Zariski) open subsets, there is no guarantee that it contains a rational point.

Comment: @abx: You are of course completely right, the question is much more subtle.