# Existence of a subspace of having no isotropic 2-plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be  a vector space of dimension $n$  over the field $\mathbb {Q} $.  A subspace $W$ is isotropic for a skew-bilinear form  $\alpha$ on $V$ if $\alpha(x,y) = 0$ for all $x,y \in W$.
More generally, if $\alpha = \{\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2},\dotsc,\alpha_{k}\}$ is a collection of $k$ skew forms on $V$  then a subspace $ W $ is isotropic for $ \alpha $ if it is isotropic for each $ \alpha_{i} $.
Now suppose   $\beta = \{\beta_{1}, \beta_{2},\dotsc,\beta_{n}\}$  is a collection of $ n $ skew forms that has no isotropic subspace of dimension $2$, and    $\gamma = \{\gamma_{1}, \gamma_{2},\dotsc,\gamma_{n-1}\}$  is a collection of $ n-1 $ skew forms which also has no isotropic subspace of dimension $2$. Then always can we have an ($ n-1 $)-dimensional subspace in the $ \mathbb{Q}$-space generated by $\{\beta_{i};i=1,2,\dotsc,n\} $ which has no isotropic subspace of dimension $2$? We can consider the case for  $ n= 6 $.     .

Comment: please state the question more clearly - using `?`

Comment: The absence of a question mark appeared just to be an accident of grammar, not of the conceptual formation of the question; I edited to include it. \\ How, if at all, is this question related to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398253/maximal-common-isotropic-subspace-for-a-finite-family-of-skewforms?

Comment: No @ Lspice question  is not similar. In first 4 or 5 lines there is the definition  of isotropic  subspace.

Comment: What do you mean by "the $\mathbb{Q}$-space generated by $\{\beta_i\}$"?

Comment: @Antoine Labelle the $\mathbb {Q}$ space generated by ${\beta_i}$ means the vector space $ S =\{c_1\beta_1 + .....+c_n\beta_n;c_i \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Comment: So your $S$ is a subspace of the space of all skew-symmetric bilinear forms? I still don't understand the question, since a subspace of $V$ is isotropic under all elements of $S$ if and only if it is isotropic under all $\beta_i$, so the conclusion seems trivial from the assumption than the set of $\beta_i$ has no isotropic subspace of dimension $2$.

Comment: Also you introduce the collection $\gamma_i$ without mentionning it again in the conclusion, I don't understand what this collection is doing there.

Comment: @ Antoine Labelle  the $ n$ skewforms  $ \beta $ have not common isotropic 2-plane does not imply that  for any $ n - 1 $ skewforms in $ S $  do not admit a common isotropic 2-plane . And here $ \gamma $ contains $ n-1 $ skewforms  and it assurance that there is $ n-1 $ skew-forms which also have no isotropic 2 plane .